# how to return a value from fs.accessAsync

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to check if a specific file. folder or directory is accessible for reading or not. I used the below posted code. the code works, but i would like to 
know the following:

1- when the error message will be printed? will it be printed when for example, the file does not exist? i tried an inexisting file but the error messagewas 
never printed.

2- how to return a value from the fs.accessSync()? i would to , for example, to return 1 if the file is accessible for read, and return 0 if not.
as shown in the code, i tried to return 1, but then the console prints "undefined".

please provide answers for the questions

**code**:

```
const d = fs.accessSync(path, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
if (err) {
console.log('is not readable is readable________________');
}

return 1;
});

console.log(d);
```

Comment: The way your code is now, the callback will never be called because you are using the `Sync` version of the access method.  `accessSync` does not take a callback parameter.

Comment: @VtoCorleone would ypu please clarify what do you mean by callback?is it the if Statement i mentioned in the code?? is there any way to achieve what I am looking for??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `accessSync` as if it's an asynchronous method.

`fs.access` has an async method and a sync method:

synchronous method - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode

This is how you should be using `accessSync`

```
const checkPermissions = file => {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(file, fs.constants.R_OK);
    console.log('can read/write');
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('is not readable is readable________________');
    return false;
  }
};

if (checkPermissions('./some/location/file.pdf')) {
  console.log('I have permissions to the file');
} else {
  console.error('I do NOT have permissions to the file');
}
```

asynchronous method - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback

A callback is a method passed in to a function as a parameter to be executed at a later time.  It's a core piece of node.js and I highly suggest reading up on it.  The node community has been moving on to promises and now async/await but it's still important (in my opinion) to understand how callbacks work to really understand the newer syntax of promises or async/await.

Answer (score 0):

As per the nodejs docs,fs.accessSync doesn't support callback, you have to use try catch for it

```js
try {
  fs.accessSync('etc/passwd', fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK);
  console.log('can read/write');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('no access!');
}
```